# fancybox is jumping my content when I have added overflow: hidden to only see 6 images on the page

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

Implemented Fancybox and have only allowed user to view 2 row (6 pictures) but the other images can still be seen in lightbox when opened, however when you exit the lightbox on image 8 it jumps the content to that image when I want it to stay with the first 6 images.

https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `$.fancybox.defaults.backFocus = false;` to prevent placing focus on active element after closing the instance.